# Change \part counter to text: from I to ONE

Tags: counters, document-classes, parts

I have included the `\part` command into my dissertation in `\documentclass{report}` which automatically uses Roman numerals: I, II, etc. as its counter.

Is it possible to change these to text/string counters: ONE, TWO, etc.?

Edit #1:

I used the first answer, but both work. However, I thought that `\part` was all CAPS, but it's not! So I used this:

`\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Numberstring{part}}`

to give "Part One" "Part Two" etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`fmtcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) and specify the part counter representation in the following way:

```
\usepackge{fmtcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\NUMBERstring{part}}
```

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\NUMBERstring{part}}
\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  \renewcommand\thepart{\ifcase\value{part}\or ONE\or TWO\or THREE\fi}
```